# How can you swap caps lock and control on a Magic Keyboard (external bluetooth) with a MacBook Pro?

Tags: macos, mac

I know how to swap caps lock and control on the native laptop keyboard. Cannot figure it out for the external keyboard.

Using MacOS Monterey version 12.4.

Comment: Do these help you: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263983/is-it-possible-to-swap-option-and-command-keys-for-a-specific-keyboard, https://discussions.apple.com/thread/251926071, https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/225089/swap-cmd-and-alt-only-on-external-keyboard

Comment: Drop menu at the top of the pref pane.

Comment: @1574717 yes, I didn't notice the selector. That totally solved it. Thanks!